# How to execute and parse query select to json inside an object returned by hibernate?

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa

This is a tricky one but I'll try to explain myself as better as I can.

I have this method inside a controller class:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", params = {"user"}, method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, User>> getUser(@RequestParam(value = "user") String ldapId) {

    User user =  userService.findUserByLdapId(ldapId);

    if(user == null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);


    Map<String, User> result = new HashMap<String,User>();
    result.put(User.class.getAnnotation(JsonRootName.class).value(), user);


    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

};
```

That one returns a json like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "Carolina Ponce",
        "ldapId": "f8cygqn",
        "email": "carolina@blabla.com",
        "uType": "Administrador",
        "deleteFlag": "",
        "typeAccess": "",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 2,
                "roleName": "Account",
                "sections": []
            },
            {
                "roleId": 1,
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "sectionName": "Dashboard",
                        "components": [
                            {
                                "componentId": 1,
                                "componentName": "Rubros",
                                "componentQuery": "SELECT Vertical_Id AS ID, Vertical_Desc AS NAME FROM D_DW_COMERCIAL.BAS_Vertical ORDER BY Vertical_Desc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see I used hibernate and `@OneToMany` annotation to achieve this. A user has a list of roles, a role has a list of sections and so on.

At the end I have a query stored in a table as you can see in `componentQuery`. The purpose of that query is to bring to the frontend something that will be rendered as a list, but that query will be different for each component, that's why I can't use hibernate to get the data of the select.

I think that I need a way to, once I have the user returned by the userService, get that `componentQuery` execute it and put the result of that execution in the same json to be able to render that data then.

This is the way I found to achieve this, but I listen to other alternatives too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic way to obtain list of lists of objects that represent a query result cells, so you can put them into JSON.

```
// Here I assume that component query is obtainable from User entity
String componentQuery = user.getRoles().get(X).getSections().get(Y)
                            .getComponents().get(Z).getComponentQuery()

Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(componentQuery);
List<Object[]> objects = query.getResultList();

return objects;
```

You can transform `List<Object[]>` to `List<List<Object>>` if you doubt your JSON serializer can handle `Object[]`

The only flaw is that column names of the query result would be unknown (hence they couldn't be passed and displayed at frontend), only data itself would be available. However, if you need column names then you can place them along with componentQuery.

So instead of

```
"componentQuery": "SELECT Vertical_Id AS ID, Vertical_Desc AS NAME FROM D_DW_COMERCIAL.BAS_Vertical ORDER BY Vertical_Desc"
```

you will have something like

```
"componentColumns": ["ID", "NAME"],
"componentQuery": "SELECT Vertical_Id, Vertical_Desc FROM D_DW_COMERCIAL.BAS_Vertical ORDER BY Vertical_Desc",
"componentResultSet": [
     ["1", "Name1"],
     ["2", "Name2"],
      ....
]
```

Comment: Do I need a class to cast `List<Object[]>` ?